# Why IFNULL doesn't port from left join?

Tags: mysql

Basically I want a column to to return 0 if null. I'm using the ifnull inside a nested statement, when I run the nested statement by itself the column returns 0, but when I run the whole query I get NULL again. This is my code:

```
SELECT Text, Verbo, Objeto, mPosts FROM Posts
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) AS mPosts FROM `Posts` WHERE Date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) GROUP BY `Verbo`,`Objeto`) AS B ON Posts.ID = B.ID
```

I could move the IFNULL to the main select statement, but I would rather not:

```
SELECT Text, Verbo, Objeto, IFNULL(mPosts,0) FROM Posts
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS mPosts FROM `Posts` WHERE Date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) GROUP BY `Verbo`,`Objeto`) AS B ON Posts.ID = B.ID
```

Why I can't do it on the nested statement? Can it can be done any other way so that I don't have to use it on the main query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting `NULL` for `IFNULL(COUNT(*),0)`, it is because the `LEFT JOIN` is not matching with your `ON` clause of `Posts.ID = B.ID`, so **all** values in the right table will be `NULL`.

So yes, you will need to move `IFNULL` to the top-level `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I got it. It was a dumb question. I'll just add IFNULL on the top level query and wrap it on another SELECT statement so that I can work with it without having to use IFNULL anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You must have the `IFNULL` on the outer query.

The `COUNT(*)` in the inner query is not returning a NULL, the NULL is being created by the LEFT JOIN operation, when a row on the left side does not have a matching row from the row source on the right side.

This query is equivalent to yours:

```
SELECT a.Text
     , a.Verbo
     , a.Objeto
     , c.mPosts
  FROM `Posts` a
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT b.ID
              , COUNT(*) AS mPosts
           FROM `Posts` b
          WHERE b.Date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
          GROUP BY b.`Verbo`, b.`Objeto`
       ) c
    ON c.ID = a.ID
```

---

The reformatted query makes it more obvious where the problem is.

Your inline view (the subquery) is performing a `GROUP` BY on two columns, and then returning the value of `ID` from some one row that is included in each of the count values.

(Other relational databases would throw a "non-aggregate in select list not in group by" type exception with this statement, where MySQL is more liberal, which is both a convenience and a curse.)

The result set returned by the query is quite odd. It's not clear what result set you want returned here.

The row from the "count" subquery is going to get matched with only one row included in each value of COUNT().  (Any time that COUNT(*) is greater than 1, there's going to be a row in the outer query that doesn't have a matching row from the inline view... that GROUP BY is collapsing all of the ID values of the included rows down to just one ID value of some one row that is included.

I hesitate to make any suggestions, because I'm not clear on what you want returned.

One thing you could do is to remove the predicate from the WHERE clause, and instead check that condition in the aggregate, something like this...

```
SELECT a.`Text`
     , a.`Verbo`
     , a.`Objeto`
     , c.`mPosts`
  FROM `Posts` a
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT b.ID
              , SUM(IF b.`Date` >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)) AS `mPosts`
           FROM `Posts` b
          GROUP BY b.`Verbo`, b.`Objeto`
       ) c
    ON c.ID = a.ID
```

That may reduce the number of NULL values, but it doesn't address the more fundamental issue of the LEFT JOIN generating NULL for any row on the left side that don't have a match from the right side.